# Create multidimensional array from table where duplicative IDs have the same parent Key

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a table like this:

```
--primary id---office id----
|----1-------|---10--------|
|----2-------|---10--------|
|----3-------|---20--------|
|----4-------|---10--------|
|----5-------|---20--------|
----------------------------
```

I want an object/array like this:

```
Array = array(
  "10" => array(
      "Primary ID" => 1,
      "Primary ID" => 2,
      "Primary ID" => 4
   ),
  "20" => array(
      "Primary ID" => 3,
      "Primary ID" => 5
   )
)
```

My query would be:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY office id
```

Is there a better query for this case?
Is there a simple and small method for creating an Array like that above?

EDIT: I am using SQL Server for this... so sadly no GROUP_CONCAT etc... ):

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Its better to use [LISTAGG](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030) function .
i.e.

```
SELECT office id, LISTAGG(primary id, ', ')
FROM table
GROUP BY office id
ORDER BY office id
```

once you get the result of above sql, we can tokenise each row by delimiter ',' and put the tokenised data in array.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT primary id, GROUP_CONCAT(office id) as office_id
FROM table
GROUP BY primary_id;
```

This will return the results as:

```
primary_id   office_id
---------------------------
10           1,2,4
20           3,5
```

This would make it easier for you to process it and store it in array.